# $\frac{2s}{q}+\frac{N}{r}= \frac{N}{2} \implies q< \frac{4N+2}{2N-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $q, r \geq 2, \frac{2s}{q}+\frac{N}{r}= \frac{N}{2}, s\in [ \frac{N}{2N-1}, 1)\subset (\frac{1}{2}, 1), N\geq 2.$

> Question: Can we conclude that: $q< \frac{4N+2}{2N-1}$?

My attempt: We have $\frac{2N}{2N-1}\leq 2s <2,$ so $\frac{2N}{2N-1} < q.$

Answer (score 1):

No, we can't.

$$\frac{2s}q=N\left(\frac12-\frac1r\right)$$
$$q=\frac{2s}N\cdot\frac{2r}{r-2}$$

For $r\in(2,2+\frac1{N})$ we have
$$q>\frac1N\cdot\frac4{1/N}=4>2+\frac4{2N-1}=\frac{4N+2}{2N-1}$$